# How do I get the position of a substring that was formatted by getString()?

Tags: java, android

How can I get the position of the substring that was read in by
`getString(int resId, Object... formatArgs)`?

For example I've got these resources

```
<string name="fruit">pear</string>
<string name="sentence">I like a <xliff:g id="fruit" example="apple">%s</xliff:g>.</string>
```

and read them in by

```
String fruit = getString(R.string.fruit); // = "pear"
String sentence = getString(R.string.sentence, fruit); // = "I like a pear."
```

I'd like to know where the word "pear" starts for example for underlining it. When the mentioned fruit is at the end of the sentence I can go for

```
int pos = sentence.length() - fruit.length() - 1;
```

but this breaks as soon as this changes (for example in a different language). I could search for `fruit` in `sentence` but this might break as soon as the same fruit gets mentioned twice for example.

Any ideas about how I can do this **reliable**? Sadly changing the implementation of resources and data parsing is not an option.

Comment: "Sadly changing the implementation of resources and data parsing is not an option" -- does this mean you can't change the string resources _at all_? Can you change the `xliff` tag even?

Comment: I noticed a bug of a software in my native language and that it's present in other languages as well (actually it's implemented with `int pos = sentence.length() - fruit.length() - 1;` right now). I want to fix this via code because otherwise every file for every language has to be modified. As the `xliff` tag is in the resources I'd say it's set in stone as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to change your string resources to use the `<annotation>` tag instead of the `<xliff:g>` tag:

```
<string name="sentence">I like a <annotation id="fruit" example="apple">%s</annotation>.</string>
```

If you can do that, then you can retrieve the string resource as a `SpannedString` using `getResources().getText()` and then inspect the spans:

```
SpannedString spanned = (SpannedString) getResources().getText(R.string.sentence);
Annotation[] spans = spanned.getSpans(0, spanned.length(), Annotation.class);
int startPosition = spanned.getSpanStart(spans[0]);
```

Then you can format it for display:

```
String fruit = getString(R.string.fruit);
String sentence = String.format(spanned.toString(), fruit);
```

---

If you can't change your resources at all, you can do something similar by using `getString()` without extra parameters to retrieve the string with its format arguments (`%s`) and then use `indexOf()` on that:

```
String text = getResources().getString(R.string.sentence);
int startPosition = text.indexOf("%s");
```

And then format it for display the same way:

```
String fruit = getString(R.string.fruit);
String sentence = String.format(text, fruit);
```

This is worse for many reasons (the string could theoretically include `"%s"` as a non-format-argument substring, you need to know the exact specification of the format arguments ahead of time, etc). But it might be the best you can do if you can't change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can split Your string like this:

```
 String[] parts = sentence.split(" " + fruit + " ");
 String part1 = parts[0];
 int pos = part1.length() + 1;
```

part1 is a string that contains everything before " pear ", so its length is the position where word "pear" starts minus 1 (we need to use " " before and after the word to ensure that we will not find it as part of unrelated word in sentence).

Comment: That's some nice idea but this breaks for sentences like "I like pears as pears are my favorite fruit." (`part1 = "I like"`, `part2 = "as pears are my favorite fruit."` - assuming it splits at first opportunity). So I wouldn't deem this as reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) method

```
int pos = sentence.indexOf(fruit);
```

Comment: copy-paste: That's some nice idea but this breaks for sentences like "I like pears as pears are my favorite fruit.". So I wouldn't deem this as reliable.